# URLs in AXIS web services

Tags: java, apache-axis

Is it possible to map URL according web 2.0 standard in AXIS Web Service without using WSDL? For instance:
http://foo.com/user/login/2255  - ???

http://foo.com/user?action=login&id=2255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL scheme from your example is commonly referred as a REST service (in contrast to SOAP service, heavily dependent on WSDL). Seems like Axis2 [supports](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/rest-ws.html) REST services, but I've never tried it.

Using JAX-RS standard you can create REST services from plain POJOs, without the need for WSDL (though Axis2 doesn't seem to support JAX-RS yet).

Comment: As I understand from reference, to map URL I anyway should use WSDL. Is it possible to map web 2.0 URL without WSDL?

Comment: With [JAX RS](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features) you only use annotations, although technically there is a WSDL specification for REST services as well. Axis seems to insist on having WSDL, but if you move to some JAX RS implementation, you won't need it.